# Wordpress: auto select category based on image aspect ratio

Tags: php, html, wordpress, image

I'm looking to create a system that when I create a post and upload and set a featured image, based on the featured image aspect ratio wordpress selects one of the three categories created (Landscape, Portrait, or Square)

Iv'e been searching for hours on how to achieve this and for the life of me I cannot find anything. Also I'm a pretty big noob in web development so if anyone can help; please provide code, simplified solutions, or detailed information.

Thank you!

NO PLUGINS!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: For example: If I upload a image that is 16:9 it auto selects the category "landscape" If the image if 1:1 then it auto selects "square" if the image is 9:16 then it auto selects "portrait".... Depending the the aspect ratio of the featured image to have wordpress auto select the category of the post: "landscape", "portrait", Or "Square".

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress works with the hooks concept: at certain events it calls all functions attached to that event. When you save a post, for example, wordpress executes `do_action('save_post', $post_id)`, so you can work on the recently saved content. I'm providing here a non tested code, but it will at least serve as a start to you finding the way.

```
function check_thumbnail_size($post_id) {
    if (has_post_thumbnail($post_id)) {
        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id), 'full');

        if (is_array($thumbnail)) {
            $width = $thumbnail[1];
            $height = $thumbnail[2];
            $ratio = $width/$height;

            if ($ratio == 1) {
                $term_slug_or_id = 'ratio'; // change this to your term slug or ID
            } elseif ($ratio > 1) {
                $term_slug_or_id = 'landscape';
            } else {
                $term_slug_or_id = 'portrait';              
            }
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $term_slug_or_id, 'YOUR_TAXONOMY_NAME_HERE', TRUE); 
        }
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'check_thumbnail_size');
```

Hope it helps!